# Getting the path of %AppData% in perl script

Tags: perl

Could anyone can help on this one:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use File::Copy;
use Win32;
use Config;
use Backticks;


#print "$^O\n";
#print "$Config{osname}\n";
#print "$Config{archname}\n";

#Win7Professional (32-bit) Service Pack 1
#Win8Professional (64-bit)
#print "\nOS: ", $osversion;

my $osversion = Win32::GetOSName();
#my $localConfPath = `\%localappdata\%`;
my $localConfPath = system("\%localappdata\%");
my $localConfPath = system(`\%localappdata\%`);

#print "$env:APPDATA\n";
exec(`\%localappdata\%`); if($@) {  print "$@\n";  }

#print "PO: $localConfPath\n";
```

I need to get the "localappdata" path using perl script. And also Windows OS based output it would be better.

"C:\Users\laser\AppData\Local"
"C:\Users\laser\AppData\Roaming"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $localConfPath = $ENV{localappdata};
my $appdata = $ENV{appdata}; 

print $localConfPath;  #will print the app path - C:\users\xxx\AppData\local
print $appdata; #prints - C:\users\xxx\AppData\Roaming
```

Comment: Some narrative would make this a better solution

Comment: This doesn't work in GitBash on Windows 10. I get error `Use of uninitialized value in print at line 7/8`. Any ideas how to make it work?