# Access Perl environment (shell) variables in Windows - $ENV not working

Tags: windows, perl, shell, git-bash, activeperl

### The issue

I found out how to use windows environment variables (e.g., `%AppData%`, `%HomePath%`, `%SystemRoot%`, etc.) in this SO post:

[Getting the path of %AppData% in perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312891/getting-the-path-of-appdata-in-perl-script)

Here is the code snippet that was chosen as a working, correct answer:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use warnings;
 use strict;

 my $localConfPath = $ENV{localappdata};
 my $appdata = $ENV{appdata}; 

 print $localConfPath;  #will print the app path - C:\users\xxx\AppData\local
 print $appdata; #prints - C:\users\xxx\AppData\Roaming
```

However, this is not working on my machine in my code for some reason. My scripts work without the shebang (#!) line so I tried the script both with and without it, to no avail.

### My set-up

I'm using the Perl that comes with GitBash, if that makes a difference.

### What I've tried

I tried a simple Perl command line execution:

```
perl -e 'print %ENV{AppData}';
```

This didn't work. I also tried the following alternatives:

```
perl -e 'print %ENV{APPDATA}';
perl -e 'print %ENV{appdata}';
```

That also didn't work. Here's the error I get (the same for all 3 versions):

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "%ENV{AppData"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I even tried to use the code from the SO post I mentioned in it's own file. That code doesn't work either. With the code from the post I get this error:

```
$ perl /c/Users/User1/Desktop/ehCode_testingWindowsEnvironmentVariables_01.pl
Use of uninitialized value in print at /c/Users/User1/Desktop/ehCode_testingWindowsEnvironmentVariables_01.pl line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in print at /c/Users/User1/Desktop/ehCode_testingWindowsEnvironmentVariables_01.pl line 8.
```

The lines in question then are these:

```perl
print $localConfPath;  #will print the app path - C:\users\xxx\AppData\local
print $appdata; #prints - C:\users\xxx\AppData\Roaming
```

I don't see why they shouldn't work.

I've checked Perl Monks, Perl Maven, Stack Overflow, and other popular Perl resources, to no avail. Even Active State did not have the answer.

Comment: Note that it's `$ENV{...}`, not `%ENV{...}` when trying to access individual items in a hash.

Comment: Also, for one-liners on Windows, you typically need to use double-quotes: `perl -E "..."`. I've never used git bash before, so this may not apply there.

Comment: Doh! Thanks @stevieb ... That was the issue. Everything else was fine. `$ perl -e 'print $ENV{APPDATA}';` works perfectly.

Comment: I've made it an answer since it did resolve the issue.

Comment: @stevieb, It depends on the shell, not the Perl. If he's using `bash`, then single quotes were appropriate.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks. I'm aware it's the shell, but never have used git bash before, I wasn't sure if it was a true bash shell, or some trickery still wrapped in the Windows `cmd.exe` shell or not.

Comment: It wouldn't be bash if it didn't accept bash commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access individual items of a hash, you need to use the scalar sigil, `$` as opposed to the hash sigil, `%`:

```
perl -e 'print $ENV{APPDATA}'
```

Comment: Also, for those seeing this answer marked correctly, another thing to be mindful of is that Windows uses ALL-CAPS and is case-sensitive (for the hash key).

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 just did some testing. In `cmd.exe`, env vars are not case-sensitive. `appdata` works just fine, as does `programfiles` (for `ProgramFiles`). It's likely the bash shell forcing things to remain sane by using proper case (I can't confirm that though).

Comment: Thanks @stevieb, I'll look into that.